# Should a user reward you with a bounty if they said that they would?

Tags: discussion, bounty

If a user states that your only answer helped them find and solve the problem in a question with a bounty, does it mean you should be entitled to the bounty?

I spent about an hour pouring over sample code and docs to help the questioner here and tried to really understand the code. I offered some code suggestions and some pointers I think the questioner missed: [Cannot save processed fingerprint image with VeriFinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918095/cannot-save-processed-fingerprint-image-with-verifinger/32942292)

Comment: depends.... do you have a link so we can assess what's up? Normally if you do, then yeah I would assume the bounty should be yours

Comment: Good idea, I've updated the question

Comment: yeah... he tells you he will award it when he can. You can't award a bounty before a fixed period of time :) no worries

Comment: **I Am Not a Lawyer**, but generally speaking, it seems to me that if someone puts up a bounty on their own question, they should have the freedom to use it however they see fit. There's no legal contract binding them to reward you with their bounty...and no, a promise made in a comment is not the same as a formally written contract.

Comment: @Cupcake I understand that, but I helped them solve the problem, so isn't that deserving of the bounty? And to put up a bounty to get attention, find the answer and not award it is not conducive to the community of SO. I also now realise that I've drawn more attention to it, reducing my chances of getting the bounty ;)

Comment: It doesn't matter what you think you deserve. The only contract that would be broken is the *social* one. I don't think anyone would ever force the OP to give someone a bounty, even if he initially said that he would.

Comment: @user3791372 definitely with you on "that's the way it SHOULD be", but the OP can still decide to wait. I would see a scenario where the OP waits the full time of the bounty in case something better comes along, even if you've helped him out of his current predicament. Of course, in this instance, this is a guy who told you straight up "I'll give it to you". So I guess he SHOULD. If he doesn't, remember him as a liar and don't look at his bounties? not much to do here.

Comment: Would there be no negative effects to the user? User/s could make a habit of starting a bounty, getting the answer, and doing a runner

Comment: @user3791372 they still lose the rep, so it won't really help them to run, except it'll aggravate someone who, for sure, won't touch their NEXT bounty

Comment: I thought they'd only lose their rep if it receives more than two up votes?

Comment: @user3791372 no, the rep cast on a bounty is ALWAYS lost. Half of it is awarded automatically to the top upvoted answer posted AFTER the bounty started, IF it has 2 upvotes. But the OP always loses his rep. It's the price for being on the "featured" page for a week

Comment: Ah that makes sense!

Comment: For the OP, there's little benefit to closing down the bounty any earlier than required - if it stays up, they might get other, even better (or just different) answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does it mean you should be entitled to the bounty?

Morally? Yes, probably. If the situation is like you describe the OP *should* award you the bounty.

"Legally" - as in, should we be able to force the OP to do so? No.

There are no binding, enforceable rules about how a bounty should be awarded, nor should there be.

The bounty amount is lost to the OP in either case, so your fear that

> User/s could make a habit of starting a bounty, getting the answer, and doing a runner

is unlikely to be a widespread problem.

You can make your point in a (polite) comment.

If it doesn't have the desired effect, shrug it off and move on.

Reputation is a very imprecise reward system. Things like this happen; the opposite does, too: you will gain unearned reputation at some point, in some situation in the future.

Comment: You sure do know how to make a guy feel bad for the reputation that he didn't earn...

Comment: @Cupcake I speak from experience! I own tens of thousands of beautiful, ill-gotten rep points.

Comment: @Pekka웃 now I feel like hunting down a crappy post of yours (if you have any) and randomly upvoting it

Comment: @Cupcake Hey, I earn reputation! Negative reputation is still rep!

Answer (score 3):

#### Generally

> does it mean you should be entitled to the bounty?

If you mean to imply that there should be someone forcing the award of the bounty to you, then no, it won't happen. Generally, bounty givers can give the bounty to whichever answer they want, even if they thanked you, even if they say your answer is the best thing they've seen, and nobody will jump in to give you the bounty if they do not.

Yes, it can suck quite a bit when there is clear evidence you've solved the OP's problem but you don't get the reward. I've been there, but there's no recourse.

#### Your specific case

**Your worries are quite premature!** Relax! In your specific case, the OP said in the comment that your answer was helpful and you'll get the bounty. I'd agree that it would suck if the question got no better answer and the OP let the bounty lapse.

**However, there are still 6 days to the bounty period.** Someone could conceivably post a better answer than yours. It happens. I've posted answers that were better than one an OP initially liked. And sometimes other folks posted answers that were better than mine. **If this happens to the question you answered, there's no reason the OP cannot award the bounty to someone else.** It would be seen as reasonable by the community.